# Generative Adversarial Network, discriminator loss becomes NAN at the same iteration even in different settings

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, gan

I am training a GAN model, and I am having a hard time fixing a NAN loss problem for my discriminator. Specifically, my discriminator's loss becomes NAN at the exact same iteration even with different hyper parameters. For instance, even if I use relu, tanh, leaky relu, the loss becomes NAN at iteration 4837. I've tried different learning rates from 1e-1 to 1e-5, but it does not solve the issue. At first, I thought it was a vanishing gradient problem, but no matter how big the loss is an iteration before, it becomes NAN at 4837. Has anyone experienced this issue? I'm using python, tensorflow, and adam optimizer.

Comment: Because it becomes NAN at the same iteration even though you're varying the hyperparameters, I suspect that the cause has something to do with the data in batch 4837. Is there anything unusual about it?

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the `tanh` activation function from the last layer of your discriminator and use `sigmoid` instead.

Comment: I'd write this as a comment, since it's a proposal and not a definite answer.